# Motd temperature reading is incorrect after processor change

Tags: temperature, sensors, lm-sensors, motd

I recently changed my CPU and MOBO to i5-12400 installed in the Gigabyte B660M DS3H DD4 motherboard. Since then I have been having wrong `motd` Temperature readings:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 21.10 (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Fri Feb 18 11:25:17 AM CET 2022

  System load:    1.26      Processes:                        450
  Usage of /home: unknown   Users logged in:                  0
  Memory usage:   10%       IPv4 address for xxx:             yyy
  Swap usage:     0%        IPv4 address for xxx:             yyy
  Temperature:    46.0 C    IPv4 address for xxx:             yyy
```

After the change I did `lm-sensors` procedure and from `sensors` I get:

```
acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +16.8°C  (crit = +20.8°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +36.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Just to be sure which reading is correct I quickly rebooted to UEFI and there 38.0°C was displayed. When the system booted `motd` again displayed `46.0 C`.

Is it something I can fix?

Comment: I'm not sure but I would guess motd is displaying the system temperature and not the CPU temperature. I suggest you inspect the motd-script by yourself. `ls -d /etc/*motd*` this should show you the places where all motd-configs are located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Message of The Day" temperature sampling time is immediately after a rather large amount of login related code has just executed. The processor is a just a little warm as a result. When you come along later, it has dissipated that heat.

The answer here is that both readings are accurate at the time they are taken.

See also [my Ubuntu forums answer to this same question](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469999&p=14071611#post14071611), with supporting turbostat data

Comment: Yes, you are right! In one session I run `watch -n 0.1 sensors` and create another one and I see the temp peaking to 46°C +/- 2°C from 36°C right after the second session starts. But it is just for a millisecond. Nice, thanks.