# Temperature shown from /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo does not match any sensors temperature

Tags: temperature, sensors

On all my systems (most of the running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), the temperature shown by `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` is different (and always much higher) than any of the temperatures shown by the `sensors` command.

How can this be? Which temperature/sensor is the landscape-sysinfo command actually showing? Why does it differ so much? It seems many others have the same problem but I did not find a solution anywhere.

Comment: See the other paths in https://github.com/canonical/landscape-client/blob/340e8fcb3b42b3c87928185ebd487bc4086fa06a/landscape/lib/sysstats.py#L97

Comment: The temperature is accurate at the time the command reads it. The issue is that the command does a bunch of other work before reading the temperature, so the temperature has already risen due to the other work. What the command should do is read the temperature first, then do the other work. I tested this command using turbostat at a high sampling rate. My processor temperature is hovering around 37 degrees C but goes up by 12 degrees or more during the command execution.

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393604/motd-temperature-reading-is-incorrect-after-processor-change/1393721#1393721) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469999&p=14071611#post14071611).

Answer (score 0):

There are various temperatures to measure, for example see this image

[image]

It might be possible that you are checking two different temps, mostly average temperature is to be considered. I am using Kubuntu by the way. Hope this helps